# How to Align in Latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

I want to align the content of each entry like a "tab" in word. How can I achieve this? I tried using `\quad` but it's just a predetermined amount of space that doesn't align the elements. I found how to do it with normal text, but the fact that it's in sections and stuff seems to make it not work or I am just doing it wrong. I am using [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/software-engineering-resume/mcvwcrmddsyw) template on Overleaf.

```
  \resumeEntryS{Programming}\quad {Java • JavaScript • PHP • HTML • CSS • MATLAB • UNITY • XML • Prolog • Common Lisp • C}
  \resumeEntryS{Applications}\quad {Eclipse • Visual Studio Code • CLion • IntelliJ • Word • Excel • PPT • SQL • GitHub Desktop}
  \resumeEntryS{Languages}\quad {Fluent in English \& French (Spoken \& Written)}
  \resumeEntryS{Operating Systems }{Windows 7 • Windows 10 • Mobile (Android) • Linux (Ubuntu)}
 \resumeEntryEnd
```

[image]

Comment: What template are you using in Overleaf?

Comment: @Werner I am using [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/software-engineering-resume/mcvwcrmddsyw)

Comment: Did you try `tabto` package? Very easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the definition of `\resumeEntryS` in your preamble and replace it with this:

```
% Entry for special (skills)
\newcommand{\resumeEntryS}[3][5em]{%
  \item[]{\small
    \makebox[#1][l]{\textbf{\color{primary}#2 }}{ #3 \vspace{-6pt}}%
  }%
}
```

This allows you to set `\resumeEntryS[<len>]{<item>}{<description>}` where the `<len>` is optional. The default is `5em`. In your case, now use

```
\section{\faGears}{Skills}
 \resumeEntryStart
  \resumeEntryS[9em]{Programming}{Java • JavaScript • PHP • HTML • CSS • MATLAB • UNITY • XML • Prolog • Common Lisp • C}
  \resumeEntryS[9em]{Applications}{Eclipse • Visual Studio Code • CLion • IntelliJ • Word • Excel • PPT • SQL • GitHub Desktop}
  \resumeEntryS[9em]{Languages}{Fluent in English \& French (Spoken \& Written)}
  \resumeEntryS[9em]{Operating Systems}{Windows 7 • Windows 10 • Mobile (Android) • Linux (Ubuntu)}
\resumeEntryEnd
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using is rather strange (it misuses a list and does not keep the scope of the font size change, and has several spurious space tokens)

```
\newcommand{\resumeEntryS}[2]{
  \item[]\small{
    \textbf{\color{primary}#1 }{ #2 \vspace{-6pt}}
  }
}
```

But a minimal change to force all the `#1` to be the same width would be

```
\newcommand{\resumeEntryS}[2]{%
  \item[]\small{% the scope of \small goes beyond this command
    \makebox[3cm][l]{\textbf{\color{primary}#1}{ #2 \vspace{-6pt}}%
  }%
}
```

that forces all the entries to be 3cm wide, adjust to whatever you need.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is going on but this does not work. I tried typing each part, understand what it was doing, and it did not work. Then I just copy-pasted it and it still isn't working. Is there something else I would need to do other than what you showed?

Comment: @Skillmon now I don't

Comment: @imaique make sure you change the ? Skillmon noted to a % then it will work. You didn't provide a test file but in your fragment you had `\quad` in soe lines but not others so the second parts will not line up until you remove the `quad